# How to resolve "Failed to send your message" problem for Contact Form 7?

Tags: plugin-contact-form-7

I am using `contact form 7` but when i m trying to send msg through contact form it gives error given below
`Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact administrator by other way.`

please help me

Answer (score 8):

You haven't given enough information, so it might have something to do with javascript conflicts, files not loading, server SMTP, etc. Best thing to do is work through the Contact Form 7 issues FAQ at [contactform7.com/faq/](http://contactform7.com/faq/)

Answer (score 3):

Check your CPANEL to make sure mail isnt going to a local mailbox.

despite any MX settings, if you have a remote mailbox somewhere else, mail sent from wordpress will first go to any local mailbox.

you must disable this in CPANEL/mx entry maintenance.

this solved my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Something goes wrong while mailing the contact form. Maybe the server doesn't allow to send mail via `sendmail()`.

You can use a plugin to send mail via SMTP. These plugins I've used before:

- WP Mail SMTP - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/
- Configure SMTP - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/configure-smtp/

Download and install in WordPress. Enter your SMTP-server on the settingspage.

Answer (score 2):

The following link details a few of the fixes that have worked for some users.

http://itsjg.com/blog/2011/03/failed-to-send-your-message-please-try-later-or-contact-administrator-by-other-way/

These fixes include:

- change the wordpress contact form area from section  ([your-name] <[your-email]>)  to  info@yourserver.com.
- add all fields inside `<label>`
- or, use “WP Mail SMTP plugin”. Then you configure your mail server details.

For me personally, I tried the first two options, but it only started working and sending emails after I installed the WP Mail SMTP plugin, and configured it to use the Gmail SMTP server (which required that I created a gmail account, as you need to provide a username and password when connecting to Gmail's server).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Contact Form 7 - FAQ](http://contactform7.com/faq/after-submitting-the-form-i-get-an-error-message/) which now covers this issue in some detail.